# SELECT * WHERE in H2 database

Tags: java, h2

I'm trying to do in my program a JDBC connection with my Embedded H2 database. The problem is that I couldn't execute a simple query with "WHERE ID =". In my databse, the ID are string not integer ('D58BE' in my example).

There is my code :

```
   public Milestone findbyId(String id) throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException {

    Class.forName("org.h2.Driver");
    Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:h2:~/dao_db", "sa", "");
    PreparedStatement prepareStatement = connection.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM MILESTONE WHERE ID= 'D58BE'");
```

The problem is that the SAME query ("SELECT * FROM MILESTONE WHERE ID= 'D58BE'") works perfectly in my embeded database (I verify the result with the h2.jar provided to manage the database). While  in eclipse, I had this exception :

```
Exception in thread "main" org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Column "D58BE" not found [42122-191]
```

I tried A LOT of things but it still never works...

Comment: It seems that single quotes `'` was removed or substituted  by double quotes `"` - actually turning D50BE into a (non-existing) column name. Why that is, is something to explore.And has more to do with some irregular java source conversion.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To execute it directly, create a statement and execute your SQL:

```
Statement statement = connection.createStatement();
statement.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM MILESTONE WHERE ID= 'D58BE'");
```

You are using a prepared statement, so you need to use placeholders:

```
PreparedStatement statement = connection.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM MILESTONE WHERE ID=?);
statement.setString(1, "D58BE");
statement.executeQuery();
```

**EDIT**

For a detailed example and also how to process a ResultSet, you can look at the following tutorial: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/processingsqlstatements.html

For your case it should be something along the lines of:

```
ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery();
while (rs.next()) {
    String id = rs.getString("ID");
    String name = rs.getNamex("NAME"); // Assuming there is a column called name.
    System.out.println(id);
}
```

Comment: It works thanks!! But can you show me PLEASE how can I use ResultSet (in this same example), if I want to create an instance of the object after recuperating its ID. Or should I create another topic ?